# OData with DTO or Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, odata, dto

In ODATA is this recommended to use separate DTO objects or use the Entity Framework model. I am using OData v4.

1. In a Web API question, I found the recommendation to use DTO as the Entity Framework model creates circular references when directly exposed via a service. Does the same issue appears for controller based on OData?
2. In OData, can we use `$expand`, `$filter` and `$select` at any depth? Suppose we have order, customer, address linked as navigational properties. Can we use use select, filter query options for all the levels? Suppose I want to search for customers age who have ordered phone category from pin code xxx. Can this be done?

Comment: I believe you can't use DTO's when using OData, You need to expose your entities to the OData. please OData tutorial for more info http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

Comment: @Eldho thanks for looking into the question. OData may be implemented without Entity Framework. I have followed few articles, one of them is [link](http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/)

Comment: I looked on the article it will be same as if use EF Model on OData

Comment: I think , OData come until you don't need have to use DTO , by the way  you can use EF or someting else data access layer on OData, and it's other things!!!